# Can I answer a question "Are you going or what?" using only "OK"?

Tags: questions

Can I answer a question "Are you going(going to party in this case) or what?" using only "OK"?

Someone told me that nobody was gonna understand me, which confused me.

Comment: Would you answer “Is the sky blue or orange?” with “OK”? If you did, you think the other person would understand what color you think the the sky is?

Comment: @DanBron But isn't "OK" in this case is an answer to first part of a question?

Comment: How does your interlocutor know if it’s the answer to the first part of the question or the second part of the question? Go back to my example: if you asked me “is the sky blue or orange?”, and I said “ok”, would you think I answered clearly or be confused? Would you think I believe the sky is blue or orange? Would you really not ask any follow-up questions to clarify? It’s a binary question and you’re not giving a binary answer. Q: “Are you male or female?” A:”Yes”. Does that seem like a clear answer to you?

Comment: But there a no defining meaning on a "or what" part. It can't be "orange" in this case.
He is asking "Are you going to the party or what?" I cant answer "yes or no" to "or what" part can't i?
So isn't "ok" can be only applied to first part?

Comment: We’re going in circles. There is a defined meaning of “or what”. It means “if you’re not doing X, then what are you doing instead?”. In your context, you can simplify and read it as  “are you going *or not*?”. You said “ok”, meaning “yes, it’s true that I’m either going or I’m not going”. Which isn’t helpful, nor an answer to the question. You can’t just ignore part of a question because you didn’t understand it.

Comment: The thing is: "... or what?" in this context is not really offering an alternative course of action, it's an intensifier. The whole sentence "Are you going or what?" really means, "Come on, get a move on!" not "Do you want to go or not?"

Comment: Did you know that you shouldn't write *gonna*? You should write *going to* no matter how you pronounce it.

Comment: @tchrist Dunno about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say: yes you can, but it would signify lack of enthusiasm.

"Are you going or what?" is said by a speaker who is impatient and eager to get going. In this particular idiom, it does *not* mean: "Are you going to go, or are you going to do something else?" It means "Come on, get a move on!"

To reply with the same level of enthusiasm, one would say something like "Not half!" or "Betcha!" or "Yeah, let's get a wiggle on!" or something of equivalent idiom.

To reply "OK" sounds a bit lukewarm, and you'd expect it to be accompanied with a sigh.

Comment: Yeah, that's how i felt. Thanks.